# Python "invalid index to scalar variable"

Tags: python, python-3.x

`for i in arange(0,3599,1):
    print(theta[i])
    if theta[i]<theta_min2:`

Here theta_min2 is just a scalar variable
Theta contains 3600 values. I do get all the values when I print it inside the for loop. Yet I don't understand why I get this error.Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your code is totally messed up.

Comment: Also, do you know that `np.arange` is not inclusive on the right?

Comment: You should also provide the traceback message. I just run your (fixed) code with a simulated list of 3600 values and it did not complain about anything. BTW, you do not need to use `numpy`'s `arange()` - simple Python `range()` is good enough. Most likely your theta is not a list or array/vector hence the crash.

Comment: you should also rewrite your loop as: `for v in theta: print(v); if v < theta_min2: ...` That is, it seems that you do not need the index `i` and `range()`.

Comment: But I have made theta an array previously.It also gives me the correct values when I print them inside the loop. I really don't understand what's going wrong.

Comment: I bet that either `theta` is not a list/array OR that the code that you posted here is not the actual code that runs on your machine.